# How to stop Scrapy CrawlSpider from following more URLs than required?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to write a crawler with scrapy that pulls pdfs from websites.
Sofar the crawler works fine in regard of downloading the pdfs.
However it follows way to many links, eventhough I have tried several things to prevent it from doings so.

The way I understand it, I can limit scrapy's Crawlspider from following links using rules with a LinkExtractor.

I have built a custom LinkExtractor (and also tried to built the rule directly without a custom Linkextractor,  but that yielded the same results.)

Basically I only want to pull PDFs from the page, any link, that does not end with .pdf should not be crawled.

The following code works so far, that only PDFs are saved using the parse_docs() method, however, I would expect the non-pdf links never to  be sent to the parse_docs() function at all.

I've tried to also use the deny attribute in the Linkextractor (idea 1) or to limit the linkextractor to only one specific PDF (idea 2), but a lot of index.php?id= links keep getting crawled.

(sorry for the long code, but I think this way you can just run the file, and not have to rebuilt half the crawler, if it should be shortend, please feel free)

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

import re
from itertools import chain
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
EXTENSIONS = [".pdf"]

class CustomLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLinkExtractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Keep the default values in "deny_extensions" *except* for those types we want
        self.deny_extensions = [ext for ext in self.deny_extensions if ext not in EXTENSIONS]
        self.allow = (r'.*\.pdf',) 
        #self.deny = ('index\.php',) #idea 1

class BremenSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bremen'
    allowed_domains = ['www.bremische-buergerschaft.de',"bremische-buergerschaft.de"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.bremische-buergerschaft.de/index.php?id=570']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rules = (
            Rule(CustomLinkExtractor(), callback="parse_docs"),
            #idea 2
            #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = ('/dokumente/wp19/land/protokoll/P19L0076.pdf')), callback="parse_docs"),
            )
        super(BremenSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def parse_docs(self, response):
        if hasattr(response, "text"):
            # The response is text - we assume html. Normally we'd do something
            # with this, but this demo is just about pdf content, so...
            self.logger.info("not parsing url: %s", response.url)
            pass
        else:
            extension = list(filter(lambda x: response.url.lower().endswith(x), EXTENSIONS))[0]
            if extension:
                # This is a pdf 
                path = response.url.split('/')[-1]                
                self.logger.info('Saving PDF %s', path)
                with open(path, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(response.body)
```

I would expect only the start_url with index.php?id=570 and .pdf links to be crawled, but when I run the crawler on the CLI it also crawls loads of other index.php?... links.

Am I misunderstanding the CLI output or is my LinkExtractor incorrect?

Comment: Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm also trying to figure this out and agree the answers around deny_extensions do not work in cases where the website redirects to the PDF or has a dynamic link which renders the PDF (many cases in today's dynamic web).   I'm involved in discussion on github - https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2303 here.

Answer (score 0):

`pdf` (without the dot) is included in `scrapy.linkextractors.IGNORED_EXTENSIONS`, so it's ignored by default. I think the following should solve your problem:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import IGNORED_EXTENSIONS
CUSTOM_IGNORED_EXTENSIONS = IGNORED_EXTENSIONS.copy()
CUSTOM_IGNORED_EXTENSIONS.remove('pdf')
```

then, in the spider's `rules` attribute you can define a rule with the following link extractor:
`LinkExtractor(allow=r'.*\.pdf', deny_extensions=CUSTOM_IGNORED_EXTENSIONS)`

Comment: This concerns the question how a pdf can be downloaded but this actually works fine. I get all the pdfs but scrapy follows way to many URLs in the process and I can't find a way to prevent it from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the `follow` Parameter of the Rule to False?

```
Rule(LinkExtractor, callback=..., follow=False)
```